# Sentences to express my regreat

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to say that I'm regretting because I didn't choose science my higher higher studies, if I had chosen science for my higher study, up to now, I would have my Bsc. completed. So, what is the best way to express my feelings in a sentence ?

So, which sentences are correct below:
1. If I had choosed 'science ' for my higher study, I would have completed my Bsc by now.
2. If I had choosed 'science ' for my higher study, I would have completed my Bsc so far.
3. If I had choosed 'science ' for my higher study, I would be passed my Bsc by now.

What does *'by now'* indicates here ? Is it correct here ?

Comment: If I had **chosen** science . . . I would have completed my BSc **by now**.

Comment: None of these sentences express feelings. They express facts about where you would be had you followed a different path. If you said them out loud, you might be able to use tone of voice to imply some emotion but, as they stand, nothing in them inherently says that you're feeling regret about your decision.

Comment: @Catija, the sentiment is implicit.  This is, alas, a very idiomatic way for English speakers to attempt to express their feelings.  It's not a great way, or a clear way, or a way I recommend, but it is perfectly normal.

Comment: No... it's not. @Codeswitcher It's a strict statement of fact. If it doesn't say "he sighed wistfully" after it or something similar... there's no implicit meaning of regret.

Comment: @Catija strict statements of fact are one of the commonest ways people attempt to express feelings. And it is absolutely implicit.  ETA: You seem to be confusing implicit and intrinsic.  It's not intrinsic, it's implicit.

Comment: @Codeswitcher Clearly, the very fact that we disagree on this shows that it's not universal.

Comment: @catija Of course it's not universal. It is, however, ubiquitous, being a particularly common form of self-expression among people who are blue collar workers, and readily observed in mass media.

Comment: StoneyB's suggestion is correct. Or you can make the sense of regret stronger by saying "If only I had chosen..."

Comment: Why did you write "if I had choosen science" in your question, but "If I had choosed science" in your sentences?

Comment: It's all because of lack of my knowledge, i want to know a good way to express my regreat. But i don't know how to. So, i have posted my question to get my English corrected.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's change **choosed* to *chosen*, the proper past participle form, in all of your examples. (You also don't need to put *science* in quotation marks; this makes it sound like you chose something specifically labelled 'science' - almost like you pressed a button with the word 'science' written on it.)

At least in the US, the phrase *my higher study* isn't readily understandable or natural. The US university system refers to a student's area of academic focus as their *major*; I'm not sure what equivalent terms are elsewhere. (I might say *choose science AS my major*, as well.) A Bachelor of Science degree is also most often abbreviated as B.S. or BS.

Let's take a look at these revised sentences, then.

1. If I had chosen science as my major, I would have completed my BS by now.
2. ? If I had chosen science as my major, I would have completed my BS so far.
3. * If I had chosen science as my major, I would be passed my BS by now.

Only the first of those sentences is grammatical and sensible; let's explore why.

Sentence 2 misuses *so far*, which can only refer to **partial completion**. You can say *I have 28 of the 32 credit hours I need so far*, meaning you're part (most) of the way to graduating but not all the way there. *I have a BS so far* implies not specifically that 'enough time has passed that I now have a BS', but rather that having a BS is only a step towards some larger goal that hasn't been reached, such as a PhD or a well-paying job. *So far* in combination with an *if* clause is quite odd - *so far* refers to things that are actually already done, and doesn't make sense with hypotheticals.

Sentence 3 is has at least two problems. First, *be passed* here is ungrammatical - it's a passive form, and shouldn't take an object. However, attempts to change it also result in problematic sentences. We could try simply making it active:

> If I had chosen science as my major, I would have passed my BS by now.

This is odd, in that *passed* here implies an **examination** of some sort, but a degree is not an examination. You could say that you had passed a final comprehensive exam, much like law students can say that they *passed the bar exam*, but you can't pass a degree.

Or, we could take *passed* as a misspelling of *past*:

> If I had chosen science as my major, I would be past my BS by now.

Again, this makes it sound like you've **overcome an obstacle**, rather than obtained or completed a degree - the emphasis is not that you have your degree, or that your degree is done, but rather that you're on the other side of it now.

Your first sentence, though, is quite fine. *By now* is used when a speaker either

1. expects an action to have happened before the time they say the sentence, but don't know if it has or not, or
2. (as here) expects an action would have happened before the time they say the sentence, if other things had happened differently

Here, it indicates that you think you would have completed your degree before now (the time you're saying this sentence).

Given the right context, sentence 1 can definitely be used to express regret (whatever the commenters might say). It depends on your intonation (if you sound sad about it) and other contexts (if, say, you're already talking about how you wish you could have done things differently). You can make it more obviously regretful, though, by using *if only*:

> If only I had chosen science as my major, I would have completed my BS by now.

Technically this sounds a bit more like two separate sentences, since *if only* usually is used in exclamations that express pure regret that something didn't happen. Something more natural might be:

> If only I'd chosen science as my major! I'd have finished my BS by now.

Or somewhat better:

> If only I'd chosen science as my major! If I had, I'd have finished my BS by now.

This sounds more overtly emotional, though, and may be out of place in formal writing.

Comment: B.Sc. and BSc (both with a capital S) are pretty common abbreviations too. Maybe it's a regional thing, but I usually see it as B.Sc. (with the full stops).

Comment: @nnnnnn It might be a regional thing (unless you're in Texas). I don't know that I've ever seen either of those; I almost always see B.S. in formal situations.

Comment: Can i use 'If only' pattern of regreating in Academic or formal writing ?

Comment: Whatever you understand, I mean Bachelor in science

Comment: I'm not in Texas: I'm in Australia. We usually write BSc - now that I think about it more I realise that the full stops are less common these days, part of the general trend towards leaving them out of most initialisms.

Comment: @yubrajsharma You probably shouldn't. It's a bit too emotional to fit in academic writing. You should probably keep it like that modified sentence 1. If you really want to emphasise your regret, you might specifically mention how you regret not choosing science.

Comment: But How ? Could you please give me examples to get me understand how to write in Academic Writing ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma 'I regret not choosing science as my major; if I had, I would have completed my BS by now.' Depending on what you're writing, though, you might be better off avoiding mentioning your emotions at all.

Comment: If i wanted to express my Emotion in writing, how would this sentence look like ? And would it wrong ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma I think Sjiveru has already shown you what the sentence would look like when you want to express your emotion in the comment right above yours. "I regret not choosing science as my major" is the part which expresses your emotion I think... ?

Comment: and what about academic writing?

Comment: That sentence Sjiveru gave you below your comment probably expresses your emotion and is useful for academic writing at the same time, but she advised you be better off not mentioning your emotion at all.